# Upload an apk for particular country on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an Android application which is country specific. Can anybody please tell me if I can upload the apk file for the particular country. Is it possible that i can upload an apk which will be listed on google play store for Germany users but wont be listed for Belgium or France users?

Comment: Seriously? Have you even tried doing that on your own?

Comment: After you upload your app to play store, go to pricing and distribution. There you can select the countries you want your app to be distributed in.

Answer (score 4):

I understand what you are trying to achieve here, it not possible to upload multiple Apk's for targeting a specific country.

Multiple Apk support is possible however not country wise. Its explained [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) in detail.

I had similar requirement: So I ended up creating multiple projects for a specific country.

example:

Project_US -> com.app.project.us

Project_IN>-> com.app.project.in

Under -> Pricing & Distribution -> Manage Countries -> Select the country for which the project/Apk was created.

Answer (score 1):

To manage which countries and territories your apps will distribute to, open **Google Play Developer Console > Pricing & Distribution** and select all the countries you'd like to distribute your app in. For the widest reach and the largest potential customer base, you’d normally want to distribute to all available countries and territories. However, because of business needs, app requirements, or launch dependencies, you might want to exclude one or more countries from your distribution.

When users visit the store, Google Play makes sure that they are in one of your targeted countries before downloading your app. You can change your country and carrier targeting at any time just by saving changes in the Google Play Developer Console.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#determine-country